# Map is not a function when passing data to populate child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Below I have a parent react component which includes a child component where I will populate the number of child components by iterating the response data.

In the render when I'm trying to map, it shows me that **map is not a function**.

```
export default class Products extends Component {
  state = {
    allComics: []
  };

 
  render() {
    return (
      <section className=" py-4 py-lg-6">
        <div className="site-content" id="content">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div id="primary" className="content-area order-2">
                <div className="shop-control-bar d-lg-flex justify-content-between ">
                  <h5>Showing 1–12 of 126 results</h5>
                  <ul
                    class="nav justify-content-md-center nav-gray-700 mb-5 flex-nowrap flex-lg-wrap overflow-auto overflow-lg-visible"
                    role="tablist"
                  >
                    <li class="nav-item mx-2 mb-1 flex-shrink-0 flex-lg-shrink-1">
                      <div style={{ minWidth: 280 }}>
                        <Select options={category} defaultValue={category[0]} />
                      </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item mx-2 mb-1 flex-shrink-0 flex-lg-shrink-1">
                      <div style={{ minWidth: 280 }}>
                        <Select options={universe} defaultValue={universe[0]} />
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>

                <div className="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
                  <div
                    className="tab-pane fade show active"
                    id="pills-one-example1"
                    role="tabpanel"
                    aria-labelledby="pills-one-example1-tab"
                  >
                    <ul className="products list-unstyled row no-gutters row-cols-2 row-cols-lg-3 row-cols-xl-5 border-top border-left mb-6">
                      {
                      this.state.allComics.map((comic) => (
                        <div key={comic.id}>
                          <AllProductsProduct
                            key={comic.id}
                            data={comic}
                            onNavigate={() => this.navigateToComic(comic.id)}
                          />
                        </div>
                      ))}
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    let {comicData} = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/allcomics");
    console.log(comicData);
    let state = "";
    if (comicData) {
      state = comicData.map((comic) => {
        return {
          id: comic._id,
          seriesname: comic.seriesname,
          issuenumber: comic.issuenumber,
          description: comic.name,
          imageref: comic.imageref,
        };
      });
    }
    console.log(state);
    console.log(this.state.allComics);
    this.setState({ allComics: state });
  }

  async navigateToComic(comicId) {}
}
```

The response that I'm getting here is like this

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5f5468fbc0c3f82c586b14d8",
        "seriesname": "Dr Doom",
        "issuenumber": 1,
        "description": "THE CRACK OF DOOM!",
        "imageref": "https://res.cloudinary.com/sdjsandssadsadsa/dsadsa",
        "publishdate": "2020-09-06T04:43:39.566Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f5497151cc5391a9ce88420",
        "seriesname": "Dr Doom",
        "issuenumber": 2,
        "description": "THE CRACK OF DOOM!",
        "imageref": "https://res.cloudinary.com/sdjsandssadsadsa/dsadsa",
        "publishdate": "2020-09-06T08:00:21.384Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f54972d1cc5391a9ce88421",
        "seriesname": "Dr Doom",
        "issuenumber": 3,
        "description": "THE CRACK OF DOOM!",
        "imageref": "https://res.cloudinary.com/sdjsandssadsadsa/dsadsa",
        "publishdate": "2020-09-06T08:00:45.452Z"
    }
]
```

Comment: Is `comicData` a string? If so, you need to parse it to an array first

Comment: just before you `return` in your render function what do you get when you `console.log("-->",this.state.allComics);`

Comment: Try initializing `state` with an array in your `componentDidMount`: `let state = [];`

Comment: Debug your code, check what exactly's the value of `comicData`. I'm not really sure why there's a destructuring in your code here: `let {comicData} = await axios.get()`, usually all the data is passed in `data` property of response instead. Perhaps you mean `let { data: comicData } = await axios.get(...)`?

Comment: i mapped it to the response.data of it and also i initiated the state inside the component did mount like Ericgio said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `componentDidMount`, you're initializing `state` with a string:

```
let state = "";
```

If `comicData` is falsy, you end up setting your state with the string instead of an array, and strings don't have the `map` method. To solve the issue, initialize `state` with an array instead:

```
let state = [];
```

Alternatively, since your component state is already initialized, move the `setState` call into the conditional so that it's only set when there's data:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  let {comicData} = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/allcomics");

  if (comicData) {
    let state = comicData.map((comic) => {
      return {
        ...
      };
    });

    this.setState({ allComics: state });
  }
}
```

Comment: this works, i am getting the data inside the comicData.data